# User32 API SendMessage to open a file from open file dialogbox in Win10 OS

Tags: c#, windows-10, user32

I have written the following c# statement to open a file

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
private const int WM_SETTEXT = 12;

private void OpenFile()
{
    var text = @"c:\devops\dev.log";
    SendMessage(ptr.ToInt32(), WM_SETTEXT, text.Length, new StringBuilder(text));
}
```

The above code works for the following open file dialog box. Opens C:\devops\dev.log
[image]

The same code fails for the following open file dialog box.

[image]

I noticed that the above dialog box has "Search" text box. Will it make any difference?

EDIT

After sending file path to open file dialog box, I tried to read from the dialog box to make sure the dialog box has correct file path text. But, I discovered that the output is "search this pc" and not the file path to open.

```
int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0xE;
 int WM_GETTEXT = 0xD;
 int textLength = SendMessage(ptr.ToInt32(), WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    
         if (textLength == 0)
         {
             return string.Empty;
         }
    
         var text = new StringBuilder(textLength + 1);
    
         int nRet = SendMessage(ptr.ToInt32(), WM_GETTEXT, text.Capacity, text);
         if (nRet == 0) return
             string.Empty;
         Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
```

Comment: Why're you trying this with the win32 API and not with the .NET OpenFileDialog class or with the win32 API GetOpenFileNameA() method?

Comment: I want to open file in notepad++ or any other editor programmatically from my program

Comment: Even with your comment, it's not clear why you're doing this *via an open file dialog* rather than just asking the shell to open the file directly.

Comment: [Notepad++ command line manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/)

Comment: Not limited to notepad++ only. Any editor. Any software which has open file feature.

Comment: `I have written the following c# statement` - have you though? Is the C# compiler actually allowing you to pass an int for IntPtr, an int for bool, and a StringBuilder for int? That is even before you consider that the correct SendMessage signature is `IntPtr (IntPtr, int, IntPtr, IntPtr)`.

Comment: My bad. Updated the code sample.

Comment: After sending file path to open file dialog box, I tried to read from the dialog box to make sure the dialog box has correct file path text. But, I discovered that the output is "search this pc". and not the file path to open. Added code sample in the question